# Netty 4.0 channel.id() returns negative integer?

Tags: java, tcp, netty

When trying to log the channel ID for debugging purposes:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // TODO: Investigate negative id
    LOGGER.info("Established Connection with = {}, Channel Id = {}", ctx
            .channel().remoteAddress(), ctx.channel().id());
}
```

I got the following:

```
2013-06-08 22:12:49,468 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] INFO  com.zeedoo.mars.server.HandshakeHandler - Established Connection with = /127.0.0.1:59236, Channel Id = -1228118933
```

And pretty much all other channel ids I got are negative also, I'm just wondering if this is an intended behavior? And if so, what's the rationale behind it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Intended or not, no idea, but it's as good a number as another if all you need is a number ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is intentional. AbstractChannel either allocates a unique negative id, or accepts a user-specifed positive unique id. The ID ranges are separated to avoid duplicate conflicts.

Comment: how do I assign an ID to the channel?

Comment: @littlejedi You call the construtor that accepts an Integer id (not every concrete channel impl does). That's how, but why is another matter.